# java script manager is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, blackjack

hi everyone im trying to create blackjack in javascript but i have a problem i cant find out why it says that the blackjack_manager is not defined when i have an entira script with it

```
 let blackjack_manager = function (){

      let game = null;

function debug(an_object) {
    document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(an_object);
}

function buttons_initialization(){
    document.getElementById("card").disabled     = false;
    document.getElementById("stand").disabled     = false;
    document.getElementById("new_game").disabled = true;
}

function finalize_buttons(){
    document.getElementById("card").disabled     = true;
    document.getElementById("stand").disabled     = true;
    document.getElementById("new_game").disabled = false;
}

function new_game(){
    let cards = null;
    game = new BlackJack();

    dealer_new_card();
    dealer_new_card();
    cards = game.get_dealer_cards();
    cards[1] = "X";
    document.getElementById("dealer").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(cards);

    player_new_card();
    buttons_initialization();

    document.getElementById("card").addEventListener("click",player_new_card);
    document.getElementById("stand").addEventListener("click",dealer_finish);
    document.getElementById("new_game").addEventListener("click",new_game);
    debug(game);
}

function update_dealer(state){
 if(state.gameEnded){
     let cards = game.get_dealer_cards();
     let msg = JSON.stringify(cards);

    if (state.dealerWon){
        msg = msg +"Win";
    }
    else {
        msg = msg + "lose";
    }
   document.getElementById("dealer").innerHTML = msg;
   finalize_buttons();
  }

}

function update_player(state){
    let cards = game.get_dealer_cards();
    let msg = JSON.stringify(cards);
        
   if(state.gameEnded){
       if (state.pBust ){
           msg = msg +"Lost";
       }
       else {
           msg = msg + "Win";
       }
        finalize_buttons();
    }
      document.getElementById("dealer").innerHTML = msg;

}

function dealer_new_card(){
 let state = game.dealer_move();
 update_dealer(state);
 debug(game);
 return state;
}

function player_new_card() {
    let state = game.player_move();
    update_player(state);
    debug(game);
    return state;

}

function dealer_finish(){
    let state = game.get_game_state();

    game.setDealerTurn(true);
    while(!state.gameEnded){
        update_dealer(state);
        dealer_new_card();
        state= game.get_game_state();
        debug(game);
    }

}
return{
    new_game= new_game
}
}();
```

and here is the html where the problem occurs

```
 !DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="js/blackjack_object.js"></script>
    <script src="js/blackjack_manager.js"></script>
    <title>BlackJack</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>BLACKJACK</h1>
      
    </header>

    <section id="game">
      <h1>Dealer</h1>
      <p id="dealer"></p>
      <h1>Player</h1>
      <p id="player"></p>
      <button id="card" type="button" >Card</button>
      <button id="stand" type="button">Stand</button>
      <button id="new_game" type="button" disabled>New Game</button>
    </section>

    <section id="sec_debug">
      <h1>Debug</h1>
      <p id="debug"></p>
    </section>

    <section>
      <script> window.onload = blackjack_manager.newgame </script>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

and here are the problems

error 1:Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

error " :Uncaught ReferenceError: blackjack_manager is not defined
tp2/blackjack_19 alunos/blackjack_oop.html:33
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

Comment: The error seems to think you have a syntax error.

Comment: `new_game= new_game` is how you assign a value to a variable, but you're returning an object, so `=`  should be `:`.  Remember that ` Invalid shorthand property initializer` probably means this issue.

Comment: yes that was the problem of the  Invalid shorthand property initializer thank you.
But i still have the manager problem

Answer (score 0):

new_game= new_game is how you assign a value to a variable, but im returning an object, so = should be :
this solved the Invalid shorthand property initializer`

Answer (score 0):

Your blackjack js probably hasn't loaded yet. Put your scripts at the very bottom of the page before the final `body` tag, with the `window.onload` script last. If necessary use `defer`.